# Error executing Xilinx ISE Design Suite .bin file(java xsetup)

Tags: 12.04, bash, java

I'm, trying to build Xilinx_Vivado_SDK_2014.1_0405_1_Lin64.bin on ubuntu-12.04
Got the below error:

```
..... 

............................................................................................................................................................... 

./xsetup: line 23: /tmp/selfgz477916398/tps/lnx32/jre/bin/java: No such file or directory

Steps I did:


$ cd /bin

$ sudo mv sh sh.old

$ ln -s bash sh

$ cd ~/Downloads

$ chmod +x ./Xilinx_Vivado_SDK_2014.1_0405_1_Lin64.bin

$ sudo ./Xilinx_Vivado_SDK_2014.1_0405_1_Lin64.bin


$java -version 

java version "1.7.0_51" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.4

(7u51-2.4.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.2)

OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Rather than pasting the error message first, please cut'n'paste (which you didn't do since the `ln -s bash sh` would have failed as a non-root user) all the commands with their output as shown in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You should never ever move files around in `/bin` - you've very likely broken your system in horrible ways now. Before rebooting even once you should `mv /bin/sh.old /bin/sh`. If anyone tells you to do something like this to run their package they are at the very best clueless.

As for `xsetup`, what does that actually do? You can just paste the result of `cat xsetup` in your question.